# SameSite attribute warning with create-react-app and Youtube

Tags: reactjs, cookies, youtube, samesite

So I created a React application using create-react-app, installed [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) npm package
and when Youtube video renders I am getting a ton of warnings about SameSite attribute, so it is caused by rendering a youtube video in my application. From what I researched, cookies are controlled from server-side and youtube should take care of cookies itself since I didn't create them. Is there anything I can do from client side to get rid of these warnings?

Warnings messages:

1. "Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute"
2. "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

I created a sandbox example of what I have:
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-night-h17gg?file=/src/App.js

However it looks like sandbox example doesn't have these warnings, but I just created exactly the same application using create-app just now and I am getting these warnings.